# Using hyphens in URLs

Tags: php, mysql, url

So I have a script that will allow me to input some text into the database using an input form, obviously this text might have spaces in, I then have a script that will fetch data according to that text and echo the text on a page with the other details in its row.

My problem is, what do I do for the spaces, how can I include hyphens or plus signs in my request for the data according to to its row like so:

```
mytext.php?text=Hello-There
```

And allow the Select query to not account for the hyphens as part of the text (or else it will not select the row - has to be exact)

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you can use the following for request

```
$url = "mytext.php?text =" . urlencode($usrinput);
```

and then for processing the request, you can use

```
urldecode($_GET['text']);
```

Comment: What exactly does that do? There is also a problem with the original request for data when using the method: mytext.php?text=Hello%20There - it seems that when making the request to the database the '%20' is also taken into account.

Comment: It takes the user input and then urlencode() encodes it in proper format. For processing, urldecode() decodes the request back to plain text.

Comment: @Alex, you really should use POST for this instead of GET.

Comment: @Alex - Radu is right, you should use POST for this. It's safe and can handle larger strings.

Comment: I would use POST but the user needs to be able to see the URL, I will give what you have said a go and see if I can get it to work, thanks a lot :)